# What does X-Accel-Limit-Rate really do in NginX?

Tags: http, nginx, webserver

[These are the docs for X-Accel-Limit-Rate](http://wiki.nginx.org/X-accel#X-Accel-Limit-Rate):

> Sets the rate limit for this single request. Off means unlimited.

Not much there. Most of the examples (I've found only two or three) I've seen set the value of X-Accel-Limit-Rate to 1024. This is obviously 1024 bytes, but per what? Or is that a total of some sort?

Without knowing what the value means it's difficult to know what it's *really* doing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently it is bytes per second. [Source](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#limit_rate)

Comment: +1.  You can see in the [source code](http://lxr.evanmiller.org/http/source/http/ngx_http_upstream.c#L3161) that nginx uses this header to set the `limit_rate` field in the request, just like the `limit_rate` directive in the conf file.